# Excel - Generalizing a SUMPRODUCT formula as an array formula

Tags: arrays, excel, performance, excel-formula, dot-product

Dear Stackoverflow members,

Thanks to the fabulous help of some MrExcel members ( [link](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/1016579-index-match-multiple-criteria-great-than-2.html#post4879161) ) I created the following SUMPRODUCT formula. The goal of the formula is to select results from a big look-up table based on four criteria: a CATEGORY (categorical), VALUE1 (numeric), VALUE2 (numeric), VALUE3 (numeric).

**Input data**

The look-up table looks as follows:
[LOOKUPTABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Bbtx.jpg)

**Wished result**

The table that I'm trying to make, looks as follows:
[WISHED RESULT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1U8E8.jpg)

**Current solution**

As a formula for the Result, I use the following (e.g. for the top-left result cell):

```
B8 = SUMPRODUCT(MAX(
(LOOKUPTABLE[CATEGORY]=$A8)
*(LOOKUPTABLE[VALUEFROM1]<=IF(B$2="";LOOKUPTABLE[VALUEFROM1];B$2))
*(LOOKUPTABLE[VALUETO1]>=IF(B$2="";LOOKUPTABLE[VALUETO1];B$2))
*(LOOKUPTABLE[VALUEFROM2]<=IF(B$3="";LOOKUPTABLE[VALUEFROM2];B$3))
*(LOOKUPTABLE[VALUETO2]>=IF(B$3="";LOOKUPTABLE[VALUETO2];B$3))
*(LOOKUPTABLE[VALUEFROM3]<=IF(B$4="";LOOKUPTABLE[VALUEFROM3];B$4))
*(LOOKUPTABLE[VALUETO3]>=IF(B$4="";LOOKUPTABLE[VALUETO3];B$4))
*(LOOKUPTABLE[RESULT])))
```

(This formula accounts also for special cases in which VALUE1 or VALUE2 or VALUE3 might be empty)

This gives the following result:
[FINAL RESULT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UmTS.jpg)

**Is there a better solution for big tables? E.g. an array formula?**

This works nicely, but once I add more rows to the result table (by adding categories D-P) and I add more columns to the table (some 40) and I add more rows to the look-up table (till 30,000), these formulas become slower. Therefore, I would like to write ONE array formula for the whole result table. If this isn't possible, then I would be happy if I could have ONE array formula per category.

**What I tried (how I failed)**

I tried using the following array formula, but it doesn't work as I would like, as it returns N/A:

```
{=SUMPRODUCT(MAX(
(Table35[CATEGORY]=$A8:$A10)
*(Table35[VALUEFROM1]<=IF(B$2:F$2="";Table35[VALUEFROM1];B$2:F$2))
*(Table35[VALUETO1]>=IF(B$2:F$2="";Table35[VALUETO1];B$2:F$2))
*(Table35[VALUEFROM2]<=IF(B$3:F$3="";Table35[VALUEFROM2];B$3:F$3))
*(Table35[VALUETO2]>=IF(B$3:F$3="";Table35[VALUETO2];B$3:F$3))
*(Table35[VALUEFROM3]<=IF(B$4:F$4="";Table35[VALUEFROM3];B$4:F$4))
*(Table35[VALUETO3]>=IF(B$4:F$4="";Table35[VALUETO3];B$4:F$4))
*(Table35[RESULT])))}
```

Further, I tried the following array formula for each category, but it doesn't work, as it gives the same result for the whole row of the category:

```
{=SUMPRODUCT(MAX(
(LOOKUPTABLE[CATEGORY]=$A8)
*(LOOKUPTABLE[VALUEFROM1]<=IF(B$2:F$2="";LOOKUPTABLE[VALUEFROM1];B$2:F$2))
*(LOOKUPTABLE[VALUETO1]>=IF(B$2:F$2="";LOOKUPTABLE[VALUETO1];B$2:F$2))
*(LOOKUPTABLE[VALUEFROM2]<=IF(B$3:F$3="";LOOKUPTABLE[VALUEFROM2];B$3:F$3))
*(LOOKUPTABLE[VALUETO2]>=IF(B$3:F$3="";LOOKUPTABLE[VALUETO2];B$3:F$3))
*(LOOKUPTABLE[VALUEFROM3]<=IF(B$4:F$4="";LOOKUPTABLE[VALUEFROM3];B$4:F$4))
*(LOOKUPTABLE[VALUETO3]>=IF(B$4:F$4="";LOOKUPTABLE[VALUETO3];B$4:F$4))
*(LOOKUPTABLE[RESULT])))}
```

**Do you have suggestions?**

Do you have some ideas, how I could solve this problem?

Thanks a lot in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `SUMPRODUCT` and `MAX` is unnecessary in this case since you are just looking up from a table. I recommend using just an `INDEX`/`MATCH` approach without `SUMPRODUCT`.

See example below, I don't have it as a pivot table but I still used your data and notice that I got the same results you did.

Note this is still an array formula. Not sure if this will solve your efficiency problem though. It might, but the bottom line is that you still have a bunch of conditions to check. The only way to pick which row has a match is to compare the condition for each column to see if a match occurs.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This solution also works. It tested it on my data and seems approximately equally fast.

What you offered is an array formula for one result cell. Do you have an idea how we could change the formula, such that it could be applied to all result cells at once?

I was thinking about the following array formula for range B17:F19, but it it returns N/A for all result cells:

`{=INDEX($H$2:$H$10;
MATCH(1;($A$2:$A$10=$A17:$A19)
*(B$12:F$12>=$B$2:$B$10)*(B$12:F$12<=$C$2:$C$10)
*(B$13:F$13>=$D$2:$D$10)*(B$13:F$13<=$E$2:$E$10)
*(B$14:F$14>=$F$2:$F$10)*(B$14:F$14<=$G$2:$G$10);0))}`

Comment: *"What you offered is an array formula for one result cell."* Yes, this is true, but with the help of relative/absolute references, the cells can be dragged over/down to get the desired result - you don't have to manually type in the formula for each cell. Why do you want a single formula for all cells?

Comment: I would want a single formula for all cells in order to speed up the calculations. Wouldn't it be faster to have a single formula?

Comment: As the logics are the same for each cell, I would expect Excel to be able to benefit from this somehow.

Comment: What you are describing gains you nothing. At best, it would make no difference. At worst, it would make the formulas much less efficient because each cell has more dependencies (since each cell is the same, they would have to look at a wider range to take into account every possibly scenario, instead of the specific scenario for that cell). Even if each cell contains *exactly* the same formula, Excel still needs to calculate the result of each cell separately.